# Как в графике от highcharts сделать нормальную отрисовку?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Нужно сделать так, чтобы линии у графика рисовались нормально. Т.е:

```js
function otherRand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
        useUTC: false
      }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
          load: function() {

            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function() {
              var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.random();
              series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          width: 1,
          color: '#808080'
        }]
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function() {
          // generate an array of random data
          var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

          for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push({
              x: time + i * 1000,
              y: Math.random()
            });
          }
          return data;
        }())
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6687fw9/2/ - значения разные и график рисует нормально всё, чётко видно, где значение упало, где поднялось.

Но почему-то в моей версии

```js
   function otherRand(min, max) {
     return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
   }

   $(function() {
     Highcharts.setOptions({
       global: {
         useUTC: false
       }
     });

     $('#container').highcharts({
       title: {
         text: ''
       },
       tooltip: {
         backgroundColor: '#000000',
         borderColor: '#000000',
         animation: true,
         shadow: false,
         style: {
           fontFamily: 'tahoma',
           fontSize: '11px',
           color: '#ffffff',
           lineHeight: '18px'
         },
         formatter: function() {
           return 'Время: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + ' <br /> Курс: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y) + '';
         }
       },
       chart: {
         type: 'area',
         marginTop: 0,
         marginLeft: -15,
         marginRight: -15,
         marginBottom: 30,
         backgroundColor: '#191919',
         plotBackgroundColor: '#242424',
         style: {
           fontFamily: 'tahoma',
           fontSize: '11px'
         },
         events: {
           load: function() {

           }
         }
       },
       xAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
         lineColor: '#000000',
         tickColor: '#FF0000',
         tickInterval: 5000,
         tickWidth: 0,
         gridLineWidth: 1,
         gridLineColor: '#414040',
         labels: {
           style: {
             color: '#f8f8f8',
           }
         }
       },
       yAxis: {
         gridLineColor: '#414040',
         title: {
           text: ''
         },
         labels: {
           enabled: false
         }
       },
       plotOptions: {
         series: {
           color: '#be610a',
           fillOpacity: 0.6,
           lineWidth: 1.2
         }
       },
       legend: {
         enabled: false
       },
       series: [{
         name: '',
         data: (function() {
           var data = [],
             time = (new Date()).getTime(),
             i;

           for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
             data.push({
               x: time + i * 1000,
               y: otherRand(51.5, 51.7)
             });
           }

           return data;
         }())
       }]
     });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6687fw9/6/ всё идёт по прямой, не смотря на то, что значения так же разные.

Почему так происходит и как сделать чтобы рисовало так же как и на первом графике?

Comment: Используйте кнопку "вставить фрагмент" для добавления кода. Сообщение должно быть самодостаточным, ссылки на JSFiddle и подобные ресурсы могут служить только дополнением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот исправленный вариант:

```js
function otherRand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
        useUTC: false
      }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
          load: function() {

            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function() {
              var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = otherRand(51.5, 51.7);
              series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          width: 1,
          color: '#808080'
        }]
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function() {
          // generate an array of random data
          var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

          for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push({
              x: time + i * 1000,
              y: otherRand(51.5, 51.7)
            });
          }
          return data;
        }())
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6687fw9/5/

В конце кода, в цикле генерируется то, что по умолчанию отображено в виде графика. В Вашем варианте было `y: Math.random()`, в исправленном - `y: otherRand(51.5, 51.7)`

Вы хотели привести график к такому виду?

Comment: Хочу уточнить, что для генерации очередной точки Вы используете функцию **otherRand()**, значит логично использовать её во всех местах, где нужно получить случайное значение точки. Если я всё правильно понял, то Вы просто упустили этот момент.

Comment: Верно всё. Хотелось бы узнать, а почему на этом примере http://jsfiddle.net/n6687fw9/6/ такая схема не работает?

Comment: Ваша схема **работает**. Вы упустили еще один момент. Взгляните на **yAxis**, если задать параметры min и max, то график изменится [изучить](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)  api можно тут (на англ.). [Отредактированный пример](http://jsfiddle.net/n6687fw9/7/)

Comment: уже лучше :) А как-то можно чтобы эти значения автоматически определялись как-то? Я про min и max.

Comment: Привожу информацию с документации по api: **min: Number**
The minimum value of the axis. If **null** the min value is **automatically** calculated.

Comment: я читал это. Но если null, то не так как надо работает. Да и из Вашего примера http://jsfiddle.net/n6687fw9/7/ график всё равно не такой резкий как здесь http://jsfiddle.net/n6687fw9/2/. Документацию я читал, но там так много всего, что голова перестаёт соображать после прочтения.

Comment: Действительно, не такой резкий. Вы должны понимать, что эта проблема не решится до тех пор, пока не будет определен числовой **диапазон**. На мой взгляд, Ваши числа слишком близки друг к другу, отсюда такой график. Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/n6687fw9/8/), график более резкий, но всё реализовано в рамках Вашего кода. Возможно есть альтернативные, лучшие решения. Мой вариант, однозначно, не панацея, но наталкивает на размышления. Еще раз посоветую изучить api и демонстрации более детально. Желаю Вам удачи.

Comment: эх. Буду думать.. Такое ощущение, что там нет того, чего мне нужно. Спасибо большое за ответы!

Comment: @ultrabatya Используйте кнопку "вставить фрагмент" для добавления кода. Сообщение должно быть самодостаточным, ссылки на JSFiddle и подобные ресурсы могут служить только дополнением. Также для выделения небольших фрагментов кода и идентификаторов следует использовать `моноширинный шрифт`, а не **полужирный**.